# Angular Controller Sending and Receiving Data to/from a Nodejs Server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

Building on this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33162038/sending-post-form-data-from-angularjs-client-to-express-node-js-server), I am working on being able to receive a response back from the node server.

**Angular Controller**

```
$scope.loginUser = function() {
      $scope.statusMsg = 'Sending data to server...';
      $http({
             url: 'http://##.##.##.##/login', 
             method: 'POST',
             data: user,
             headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
      })
}
```

Nodejs Server

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res) {
   console.log('Processing request...');
   res.sendFile('/success.html');
});
```

**How can this example be extended to be able to receive a response back from the server?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$scope.loginUser = function() {
  $scope.statusMsg = 'Sending data to server...';
  $http({
         url: 'http://##.##.##.##/login', 
         method: 'POST',
         data: user,
         headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
  }).then(function(response) {
      //do something with your response from the server
      console.log(response.data)
    })
 }
```

On your /Post route typically you would be sending data from your controller to possibly query a database and send back some data through JSON.